# Using interface constants in constructor of implementing class

Tags: java, interface, constants

My teacher gave me an excercise on interfaces i don't really know how to handle. I was given an interface and told to implement a class Book that implements that interface.

Class book should have attributes isAvailable, name and rating.

My question is, in this excercise when i will be creating an instance of book in main method then while writing rating in the constructor i need to guaratee that rating will be written in same way as are variables named in interface? And if i will write smth else then it would be a mistake cause i'm not using interface constants that i should have? I'm not sure if I understood and implemented well the book class.

```
public class Book implements BookService {

private String name;
private String rating;
private boolean isAvailable;

private final boolean DEFAULT_AVAILABILITY = true;
private final String DEFAULT_NAME = "default_name";

public Book(String name, String rating, boolean isAvailable) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
}

public Book() {    
    this.name = DEFAULT_NAME;
    this.rating = DEFAULT_RATING;
    this.isAvailable = DEFAULT_AVAILABILITY;
}

public boolean validateAvailability(){
    return isAvailable;
}
}

public interface BookService{

public static final String ONE_STAR = "*";
public static final String TWO_STARS = "**";
public static final String THREE_STARS = "***";
public static final String FOUR_STARS = "****";
public static final String FIVE_STARS = "*****";
public static final String DEFAULT_RATING = ONE_STAR;
public abstract boolean validateAvailability();  

}
```

Comment: The `interface` only requires you to `validateAvailability`. I would say that the ratings are a red herring.

Comment: Pro tip: change `DEFAULT_NAME` to your professor's most quoted Java book for some extra points.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method when you are creating a book object, pass BookService.(rating) as the parameter.

Example:

```
Book myBook = new Book(name, BookService.THREE_STARS, true);
```

Depending on how you are getting input, you might want to write a switch case to change user input into one of those constants, and then you can do the following.

```
Book myBook = new Book(name, rating, true);
```

Where "rating" has been assigned the value of one of the constants.